# How do I create a new table from the results of a dynamic SQL statement in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I'm trying to use the results from this dynamic SQL statement, to create a new table

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(MAX), @query NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT
                       ',' + QUOTENAME(c.[ClassCode])
                   FROM [Sandbox].[dbo].Test2 c 
                   FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '');

SET @query = 'SELECT [Name_ID], ' + @cols + 
             'FROM (SELECT [Name_ID],
                           [ClassCodeYN] AS [amount],
                           [ClassCode] AS [category]
                    FROM [Sandbox].[dbo].[Test2]) x 
              PIVOT (COUNT(amount) FOR category IN (' + @cols + ')) p';

EXECUTE @query
```

I've tried to use `INSERT INTO` and `CREATE TABLE` and get either

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'EXECUTE'

or

> Must DECLARE @query

errors.

Comment: You should be able to just stick a `CREATE TABLE AS <new_table_name> AS` in front of that `SELECT` like `@query = 'CREATE TABLE AS <your_new_table> AS SELECT [Name_ID], ...`

Comment: `EXECUTE @query` should be `EXEC sys.sp_executesql @query;`

Comment: Hey thanks for your response. I tried `@query = 'CREATE TABLE AS <your_new_table> AS SELECT [Name_ID], ...``` as well as removing the `AS` and get 
"Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'." - @JNevill

Comment: To add to what @Larnu said, `EXEC` without parentheses uses the variable as the name of a stored procedure. You could use `EXEC(@query)` but better to use `sp_executesql` anyway

Comment: `Create table as` .. is not sql server syntax.. I believe this is MySql and Postgresql

Comment: Unfortunately we can't run your query, so other than fixing your `EXECUTE` statement, it's difficult for us to see what the problem is, @EdwardOsorio . We can't even see what the dynamic statement that is being run will be. The best way, however, to debug dynamic statements is to `PRINT`/`SELECT` the dynamic statement, and debug that. Then propagate that solution to the statement that creates the dynamic statement. Otherwise take the time to provide DDL and DML statements for sample data so that we can run your attempt, and find out what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to just add `into <table>` to your existing query:

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(MAX), @query NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT
                       ',' + QUOTENAME(c.[ClassCode])
                   FROM [Sandbox].[dbo].Test2 c 
                   FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '');

SET @query = 'SELECT [Name_ID], ' + @cols + 
             ' INTO MyTable' +
             ' FROM (SELECT [Name_ID],
                           [ClassCodeYN] AS [amount],
                           [ClassCode] AS [category]
                    FROM [Sandbox].[dbo].[Test2]) x 
              PIVOT (COUNT(amount) FOR category IN (' + @cols + ')) p';

Exec sp_executesql @query
```